# Why Cynthia go easy on cult group who shaved her son's head?

Tags: plot-explanation, this-is-england

In [This Is England](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/This_Is_England), Cult group welcomed Shaun with shaving his head.

[image]

Then how his Mother go easy on cult group who shaved her son's head?

Comment: Skinheads are not a cult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lol, Woody and the others are apologetic.  Cynth (mum) seems to recognise that they are sincere and appear to be good kids who are just having fun.  She also appreciates that Shaun has made some friends and this should be good for him.  At this point in the film she is correct in this assessment, the gang is fun loving, kind and pretty benign - it is only when Shaun starts to associate more with Combo, Banjo and the more fanatical members of the group that things take a darker turn.